# Jest error Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am having great trouble using Vue Jest Unit Test, will definitely upvote or like if you could help. This is the most complicated installation I have ever done, which was to install Jest Unit Test and get it running. So far, I have created done the following installation steps:

1. `npm install -g @vue/cli@latest`
2. `npm install`
3. `vue add unit-jest`
4. Added `"test": "jest"` to scripts in `package.json`
5. Added `jest: true` to `.eslintrc.js`
6. The installation auto-generated an `example.spec.js` file.
7. I then ran `npm test` and now I am facing the failure error for my `example.spec.js` file.

```
Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env'

Make sure that all the Babel plugins and presets you are using
    are defined as dependencies or devDependencies in your package.json
    file. It's possible that the missing plugin is loaded by a preset
    you are using that forgot to add the plugin to its dependencies: you
    can workaround this problem by explicitly adding the missing package
    to your top-level package.json.


    Require stack:
      node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
      node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
      node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
      node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/InlineSnapshots.js
      node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/State.js
      node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/index.js
      node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js
      node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js
      node_modules/@jest/core/build/jest.js
      node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js
      node_modules/jest-cli/build/index.js
      node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js
      node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.524 s
```

Please help me, I have been spending a few hours and the installation for Jest unit test is still incomplete. What do I need to do? I am using Vue.

`example.spec.js`

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'

describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
  it('renders props.msg when passed', () => {
    const msg = 'new message'
    const wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld, {
      props: { msg }
    })
    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(msg)
  })
})
```

**Update**
Ran `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env` and this is the error message I got:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.2.0
npm ERR! Found: vite@4.3.9
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   peer vite@"^2.7.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0" from vite-plugin-vuetify@1.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/vite-plugin-vuetify
npm ERR!     peerOptional vite-plugin-vuetify@"^1.0.0-alpha.12" from vuetify@3.1.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/vuetify
npm ERR!       peer vuetify@"^3.0.0-beta.4" from @vuetify/loader-shared@1.7.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared
npm ERR!         @vuetify/loader-shared@"^1.7.1" from vite-plugin-vuetify@1.0.2
npm ERR!       2 more (vite-plugin-vuetify, the root project)
npm ERR!     dev vite-plugin-vuetify@"^1.0.0-alpha.12" from the root project
npm ERR!   dev vite@"^4.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^3.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vite@3.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue
npm ERR!     dev @vitejs/plugin-vue@"^3.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to reproduce the problem. You won't be able to do this from scratch like `vue create myapp` and `vue add unit-jest` because these ones provide a ready to use setup. The error possibly means that you added `env` to Babel config on your own. If that's the case then either stick to default config or add it as the answer suggests.

Comment: I tried doing your steps.
After step 2, `npm install`, I got an error:
`npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'path\to\project\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.`
This is to be expected - a *global* installation of `@vue/cli@latest` doesn't create any (local) `package.json` – exactly what the error message says.
It seems that you didn't do what you tell us you did.
Can you start completely from scratch and do *all* the steps that lead to the error message?
This one:
`Make sure that all the Babel plugins and presets …`

Answer (score 2):

looks like `@babel/preset-env` package is missing. This package is needed by jest to transpile the code.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env
```

then, create a file named `.babelrc` in the root directory, and add this:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

now you can run `npm run test`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried running `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env` but it is giving me an error. `npm ERR! While resolving: @vitejs/plugin-vue@3.2.0
npm ERR! Found: vite@4.3.9`. I have updated my answer above to show the error message. Please check it out! I have also added `.babelrc` to the same directory location as `.eslintrc.js` in my web folder.

Comment: try remove node_modules and package-lock.json (or yarn or pnpm lock files) and then re install the modules. then provide me feed back